# Grails g:if and string comparison

Tags: grails, groovy

I've written some code that checks to see if the user is logged in as an admin or not to limit who can make changes to other user's permissions, but the if tag is never true.  I've made sure the correct data is there by echoing it out but nothing I've found so far has given me a solution.

```
<g:if test="${session.userPermissions == 'Administrator'}">
    <g:select id="permissions" name="permissions" from="${userInstance.constraints.permissions.inList}" value="${userInstance.permissions}" ></g:select>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    ${userInstance.permissions}
</g:else>
```

Comment: What type of object is stored in session.userPermissions? The name somehow suggests that it is a list rather than a single String.

Comment: I'm setting it as a string, but maybe it is translating it to an list.  I'll have to check that out.

Comment: It is a list, I can access the string using session.userPermissions[0].  But when I am assigning it I am using a string data type.

Comment: Found the issue, I was fetching the user info from the database using a criteria.  Since it was returning a list my call to user.permissions was also returning a list.

Comment: if using a withCriteria, you can add a parameter to have it return a unique result like this: def item = YourDomain.withCriteria(uniqueResult: true) {...}

Answer (score 8):

try "java" String ways :D

```
<g:if test="${session.userPermissions.equals('Administrator')}">
....
</g:if>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I was having the exact same problem in my .gsp files where two strings (or at least I thought were strings) x and y that would display equally as ${x} and %{y} would fail the == test. Using String.equals solved the problem and the mystery.

Answer (score 1):

It ends up a groovy thing-

I used a criteria to get the user's login information.  The criteria returns a list of user variables.  I was setting session.userPermissions = user.permissions

In groovy you can access every list element's properties and retrieve them as a new list (example below).  This was giving me the list variables in my session.  It's a really cool feature, but not one you like to find on accident like this.

```
groovy> def demo = []
groovy> demo[0] = [a:1, b:2]
groovy> demo[1] = [a:3, b:4]
groovy> demo[2] = [a:5, b:6]
groovy> demo.a

Result: [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Yep, actually this syntax is a shortcut for demo.collect { it.a }. This also works for method invocations on the list's elements: list*.myMethod() returns a list containing the return values of myMethod() invoked an all elements of the original list (so-called spread-dot operator). The collect-equivalent would be: list.collect { it.myMethod() }

Comment: this could be a cause of hard to track bugs...hhmmm not great.

Comment: I really dislike this feature of Groovy (known as "GPath"). You can do exactly the same thing with `demo*.a`. I'm happy to type an extra character to make it obvious whether I'm accessing a property, or collecting a property